# Kernel Update Fails

Tags: kernel

I am not able to update the kernel on my Ubuntu 20.04 OS. After doing the commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I get these command responses:

```
me@ubuntu:~$ sudo uname -sr
Linux 5.4.0-81-lowlatency
me@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

How can I find out what is blocking the kernel update?

Comment: Your output does not show anything blocked. 5.4.0.81 is the correct kernel version for 20.04, a 16-month-old kernel for a 16-month-old OS. What exactly were you expecting to happen? Or are you asking how to get the [HWE kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack)?

Comment: Edit your question and actually include the output of the apt commands. I don't see a problem here